# Unable to trigger a duel to play out c++

Tags: c++

Working on an assignment to have a duel play out amongst three players with varying accuracy and needs them to shoot in order. Aaron has an accuracy of 1/3, Bob has an accuracy of 1/2, and Charlie never misses. A duel should loop until one is left standing.
Here is my code so far and it only ever causes the first two players to miss and Charlie wins even when the random number generator should constitute a hit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void shoot(bool & targetAlive, double accuracy);
int startDuel();

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    startDuel();

    return 0;
}

void shoot(bool &targetAlive, double accuracy)
{
    double x;
    

    x = (((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX))*1.0);
    if (x < accuracy)
    {
        cout << "target is hit!" << endl;
        targetAlive = false;
    }
    else
        cout << "missed!" << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
        targetAlive = true;
}

int startDuel()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    bool aaronAlive, bobAlive, charlieAlive;

    shoot(charlieAlive, 1.0/3);
    if (charlieAlive)
    {
        cout << "Aaron missed Charlie!" << endl;
        shoot(charlieAlive, 0.5);
        if (charlieAlive)
        {
            cout << "Bob missed Charlie so Charlie throws back!" << endl;
            cout << "Bob has been hit by Charlie!" << endl;
            bobAlive = false;
            shoot (charlieAlive, 1.0/3);
            if (charlieAlive)
            {
                cout << "Aaron missed Charlie, so Charlie throws back!" << endl;
                aaronAlive = false;
                cout << "The duel is over and Charlie wiped them all out" << endl;
                return (c++);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (!charlieAlive)
    {
        cout << "Aaron hit Charlie" << endl;
        do
        {
            shoot(aaronAlive, 0.5);
            shoot(bobAlive, 1.0/3);
            if (!aaronAlive)
            {
                cout << "Bob won!" << endl;
                return (b++);
            }
            else if (!bobAlive)
            {
                cout << "Aaron won!" << endl;
                return (a++);
            }
        }
        while((aaronAlive)&&(bobAlive));
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger

Comment: Here's your code compiled with the warnings and sanitizers cranked up to what I consider a reasonable level: https://godbolt.org/z/a3419xMhG . Resolve all of the diagnostics and see if you still have a bug.

Comment: You should not reset your random seed (`srand(time(NULL));`) every time someone shoots.

Comment: It plays out like this everytime "target is hit!
0.00546281
Aaron missed Charlie!
target is hit!
0.436598
Bob missed Charlie so Charlie throws back!
Bob has been hit by Charlie!
missed!
0.526872
Aaron missed Charlie, so Charlie throws back!
The duel is over and Charlie wiped them all out"

Comment: @pm100 I am a first semester student and we have not gotten to using a debugger yet so I cannot help with that.

Comment: Note that the `else` branch in the `shoot` function only includes the first `cout`.  It does not include the following two lines because you are missing braces around the block.  The fact that you didn't notice this means you do not have your compiler warnings enabled - which is *definitely* recommended when programming in C++.

Comment: Don't just run the program. Step through it with a debugger and make sure every line of code behaves exactly the way you expect. If it doesn't, either your expectations are wrong or you have a bug. This is often the same thing, but even when it isn't you need to fix the problem. The reason I coasted through my first year programming assignments and still had time left over to run my Champions campaigns was I taught myself to use a debugger.

Comment: first thing you should do is learn to use your debugger, do it now. It is easy and will pay huge benefits.

Comment: @pm100 it is the very next topic we are covering haha. Soon, soon. I completely missed the lack of braces in my shoot function as well as leaving srand in the function when testing. I'm running through it now to see how it plays out.

Comment: On the braces thing: many development environments have an auto-formatting tool. Run your code through it and watch what happens to the indentation. It's a stupidly easy way to kill whole families of bugs in their crib. If your code always follows a particular patter, stuff that breaks the pattern sticks out like a sore thumb and draws the eye to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the last line of shoot

```
void shoot(bool& targetAlive, double accuracy)
{
  double x;


  x = (((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * 1.0);
 if (x < accuracy)
 {
    cout << "target is hit!" << endl;
    targetAlive = false;
 } 
  else
    cout << "missed!" << endl;
 cout << x << endl;
 targetAlive = true;  <<<<====
}
```

no matter what happens before you reset alive to true before exiting

just remove that line

also move srand to main, you should only call it once.

Comment: Just changed srand to main right after posting and edited!